# Turn accordion 90 degree

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how can i turn the accordion to 90 degree on click of it for repo and bundles in the below plunkr. I am new to css. Any hekp on this is appreciated. Plunkr link - https://plnkr.co/edit/LzJKGdaQJBNsgmUkOYti?p=preview

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="treeTable" >
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="tableheight ">
    <table class="treetable-nested childtable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:5%;">
          <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" />
        </th> 
        <th >
          Name
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
          Version
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
          Size
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
        Date Modified
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
        Labels
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
        Description
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="newRepo" style="font-size:12px" data-ng-repeat="item in list">
        <tr id={{item.id}}>
            <td>
                <button class="accordion" ng-click="displayChildren(item,item.id)"></button><input class='parentCheckbox' ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" ng-change = "toggleChildren(item)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item.name}}
            </td>
            <td class="cell-members">
<!--                {{item.version}} --> 0
            </td>
            <td class="cell-members">
<!--                {{item.size}}-->  0
            </td>
            <td class="cell-members" >
<!--                {{item.date}}-->   0
            </td>
            <td class="cell-members">
                {{item.label}}
            </td>
            <td class="cell-members">
                {{item.description}}
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-if='item.children && item.children.length > 0'>
            <td colspan="7" id="bundle_1" >
                <table ng-show="item.showTree" class="treetable-nested" style="width:100%;"> 
                    <tbody ng-repeat='bundles in item.children'>
                        <tr id={{bundles.bundleId}} ng-init="parentScope = $parent.$parent;">
                            <td style="width:5%;padding-left:15px;white-space:nowrap"><button class="accordion test" ng-click='showComponents = !showComponents'></button><input ng-model="bundles.selected" ng-change="toggleChildren(bundles, parentScope)" type="checkbox" /></td>
                            <td>{{bundles.bundleName}}</td>
                            <td class="cell-members">{{bundles.bundleVersion}}</td>
                            <td class="cell-members">{{bundles.bundleSize}}</td>
                            <td class="cell-members">{{bundles.bundleModified}}</td>
                            <td class="cell-members">{{bundles.bundleLabels}}</td>
                            <td class="cell-members">{{bundles.bundleDescription}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-show='showComponents' ng-repeat='components in bundles.components' id={{components.key}} ng-init="bundleScope = $parent;">
                            <td style="width:5%;padding-left:30px;"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="components.selected" ng-change="toggleChildren(components, bundleScope)"/></td>
                            <td>{{components.value}}</td>
                            <td>{{components.Version}}</td>
                            <td>{{components.Size}}</td>
                            <td>{{components.Modified}}</td>
                            <td>{{components.Labels}}</td>
                            <td>{{components.Description}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.accordion { transform:rotateX(90deg); }`

Comment: @scott Marcus I have seen this one in other examples. But i would like to know how can i use it in my example.

Comment: You can use it exactly as @ScottMarcus described

Comment: @baao When i used exactly the same one accordion itself is not showing up. Any help. https://plnkr.co/edit/puKtIfCmUdLtqtQAwyaz?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved your problem:

Step 1: Figure out how to rotate elements with CSS. You can use the CSS [transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to rotate elements.

Step 2: Define a CSS class which would apply the transformation to the icon

```
.accordion.expanded:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Step 3: Figure out how to apply the CSS class with the transformation through AngularJS. You can toggle CSS classes with AngularJS in multiple ways.

One option would be passing the [$event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-) onlick

```
<button class="accordion" ng-click="displayChildren(item,item.id,$event)"></button>
```

and toggling the class on the element like:

```
$scope.displayChildren = function(item, id, event) { 
      angular.element((event.target)).toggleClass('expanded');
     //rest of your logic
}
```

The second option is by manipulating a variable and setting the class to [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) like

```
<button class="accordion" ng-click='showComponents = !showComponents' ng-class="{'expanded' : showComponents}"></button>
```

You can find the plunker i tried this out [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/N8Hgh0eLG4whl9SsA94h?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
.accordion:active {
            transform: rotateX(90deg);
        }
```

If you want it rotetes permanently use jquery:

```
$('.accordion').click(function(){$(this).css('transform', 'rotateX(90deg)');});
```

and if you want it rotates and rotate back by button click:

```
<style>
  .rotated {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
</style>

$('#btnRotator').click(function(){$('.accordion').toggleClass('rotated');});
```

Comment: This will rotate an `<accordion>` element (which doesn't exist), 90 degress when it becomes active and would then, rotate back when it isn't. Even if that worked, I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus, But i test this, It will be hidden until the mouse is down. **active** does not work like **hover**.

Comment: This won't work at all, since there is no such element as `<accordion>`. Also, I didn't say anything about hover. I said that even if the code were to work, the entire accordion would rotate only when it becomes active and then it would rotate back when it no longer is. That is not what the OP wants.

Comment: So So sorry and thanks for the good comment. I was thinking you say it will rotate and change back immidiately. I edited the answer.

Comment: But he says rotate on click. It means to me it must rotate only when clicked. Maybe i misunderstand.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi you are right. I want it to rotate 90 degree on click of accordion button. On another click it has to rotate back to same position. Sorry for any misunderstandings.

Comment: Which button must click to rotate back the accordion?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi On click of same button, accordion has to rotate back.

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular to attach an active class to expanded accordions that applies the CSS transform.

```
.accordion.active:before {
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Looks like you can add `ng-class="{'active' : item.showTree}"` to accomplish an active class on the button. You also already have an `:after` target for an active class so you should remove that too.